# PHP - Simple HTML Dom Questions

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

Basically im trying to scrape IMDB to check how many seasons there are, How could I basically do something like this but instead have it just output how many in total there are instead of just outputting 1 2 3 4 5 if the show has 5 seasons and if it has 10 seasons it would output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 but I just want it to output 9 if the series has 9 seasons. How could I do this?

This is my current code:

```
$seasons = $_GET['seasons'];
$url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/'.$seasons.'/episodes';

$imdb_content = file_get_contents($url);
$html = str_get_html($imdb_content);

//Grabbed Content
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',0)->plaintext;
$p1 = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',1)->plaintext;
$p2 = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',2)->plaintext;
$p3 = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',3)->plaintext;
$p4 = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',4)->plaintext;
$p5 = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',5)->plaintext;
$p6 = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',6)->plaintext;
$p7 = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',7)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',8)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',9)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',10)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',11)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',12)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',13)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',14)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',15)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',16)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',17)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',18)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',19)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',20)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',21)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',22)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',23)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',24)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',25)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',26)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',27)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',28)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',29)->plaintext;
$p = $html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option',30)->plaintext;

//Content
$content = "";
$content.= $p;
$content.= $p1;
$content.= $p2;
$content.= $p3;
echo $content;
```

Comment: A very simple, but naive approach would be to do your check in the opposite order (start at 30 and go down) and if `$p` equals something, then return just that

Comment: I dont see how going from 30 down solves anything and checking if $p reaturns anything and outputting it doesnt help at all its basically exactly what my current script does

Comment: `$p` will only be set to a truthy value if that season exists right (if that's not true, let me know)? So let's say there's 9 seasons. When the script starts and checks 30, `$p` will be falsey (either false or empty quotes, I'm guessing). When it gets down to 9, suddenly `$p` is a truthy value, so you echo that and stop your script.

Comment: Frankly a better way to do it though would be to use a while loop with a counter that increments, and continue while `$p` is truthy, and as soon `$p` is falsey you break and echo the counter - which will be equal to the number of seasons.

Comment: That does make sense ill see what I can try and do to get that made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly. Here is Game of Thrones season count by simple_html_dom.

```
<?php 
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/episodes';

$imdb_content = file_get_contents($url);
$html = str_get_html($imdb_content);

foreach($html->find('select[id="bySeason"] option') as $season){
    $last_season = $season->plaintext;
}

echo $last_season;
```

> Output is: 7

References:

[Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

[Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: Strangely this works, I read the manual a lot and it says at the end of ur find() before the end brakcet put ,-1 to get the last match but I dont understand how this one is working withouth it

Answer (score 0):

It's really as simple as:

```
echo count($html->find('#bySeason option'));
```